# How to change close spacing in a PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design, kicad, pcb-layers

I am designing a board with an STM32F103C8T6 processor. I watched some videos by PhilsLab to learn how to work with KiCad. After I watched some more videos to learn how to make my board look more aesthetic and to avoid beginner's mistakes, **I now want to change some parts of the board.**

**My old design looked something like this:**
[image]

### What I want to change

Because of **clearance** and **coupling,** I want to make a change on this specific area (pin header from PA4 to GND (on the bottom of the board.))

I would like to change the part in the green square.

The board is a 2 layer board with signals on top and GND on the second plane.

### Question

Do you think I could leave the spacing on the chip itself or would it be better to change it?

--> When changing, any tips?

### My idea

The only way I came up with, is to trace it like this:

[image]

Comment: What wrong with it now? Does it work? Why would want to put in the extra effort for a respin when you could make a mistake and make things worse?

Comment: Currently it is working well. Just thought I should change it. If it is not nessecary I will leave it that way.

Comment: It is generally better to avoid sharp corners < 90 degrees within traces or in trace to pad connections. Tight corners can have higher mechanical stress points and may be harder to clean during the PCB manufacture process.  For example the traces going to connector pins 2, 7, and 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you think I could leave the spacing on the chip itself or would it be better to change it?

For me, spacing matters when crosstalk (or coupling in general) an issue or a risk.

Crosstalk is basically a voltage induced on a conductor (trace) by a rising edge on an adjacent conductor (trace). As the risetime gets shorter the amount of crosstalk increases. So if you are not dealing with tens of megahertz (or higher frequency) signals then just leave the traces as they are.

Another thing is the source and target impedance: High impedance traces tend to pickup noise (especially if they are long).

Final thing worth mentioning here is the production capability of the manufacturer you are working (or about to work) with. They provide their production limitations (min trace width, min trace/pad spacing, etc) so take them into account

Answer (score 3):

Congrats to your board and self teached Kicad skills :)

Unfortunately some informations are missing to give you a specific answer.
In general the layout of a pcb depends on the following aspect (general overview, order doesn't mean importance):

- electrical requirements ( noise, field coupling (differential/ single ended lines), impendance (microwaves), resistance (power lines), electromagnetic compatibility in general  ...)
- thermal requirement
- manufacturing ( number of layers, thickness of stack, minimal clearancve ...)
- mechanical (dimensions, ... )

If you change your design keep always an eye an all aspects an verify that you still fullfill all requirements.

I would not recommend to change the layout just to have a bigger clearance for no reason. The manufacturer gives you a minimal clearance as a constrain and it is fine to use it. (You can set it in Kicad)

It's valid to change the layout for improving signal quality (less coupling).
Normally it is done if it not work or does not fullfill electrical requirements.

The coupling in a design depends roughly said on the layout AND the signal. If you have a hf signal close to 2 dc power lines (in fact it can be seen as virtual ground for a coplanar waveguide), you can have no problem. But if a digital signal is next to an analog signal - it will interfer.

A lot of rule of thumbs exists about these topics especially in hf designs like wavelength*3 = recommended spacing and ...
These rules make only sense under some conditions - make sure to know them.
(study electrical engineering / radio frequency or view some youtube: https://www.youtube.com/@ElectroBOOM has some nice videos about it ;))

Increasing signal quality in a system is not trival - keep also the way back of your signal (gnd backplane) in mind. From your pictures i can see some cuts in there. I would rather try to reduce these cuts by keeping the traces on the bottom as short as possible, reduce clearance between traces and move vias.

[image: redesign]